# Spurious 100% CPU kintegrityds process

Tags: linux, vmware, esxi, jenkins

I run a CI server using VMware ESXI 6.7 on local hardware. It has three hosts, running Linux, Windows and MacOS. The Linux host runs a Jenkins instance. I've recently noticed that our builds are taking much longer than usual. Upon investigation, it seems on the Linux host there is a process named kintegrityds, which is using 100% of the available (virtual) CPU cores. It is running as the jenkins user. Killing it seems to cause no ill effects, but it returns next time a build occurs, or sometimes when the server is idle.

Disk failure? This occurred out of the blue, with no configuration changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been fighting this this morning and found this via google search:

https://www.anomali.com/blog/rocke-evolves-its-arsenal-with-a-new-malware-family-written-in-golang

Seems you can reverse engineer the infection via the description there. According to the article, there should be a cron keeping this coming back. `chattr -i` is used to protect files that are part of the infection, `/etc/ld.so.preload` is modified, etc.  Will report back when I've successfully cleansed this trash.

Comment: Holy shit. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Yep, looking at my jenkins user's crontab, it was eventually downloading and executing this every ten minutes: https://pastebin.com/raw/CBEphEbb :( Mother****ers. As far as I can tell it hasn't managed any privilege escalation and has been confined to executing as the jenkins user, so hopefully I've got away without having to rebuild this server. I'm probably just going to nuke my Jenkins install from orbit and start that from scratch. On Monday.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately the client I was working with decided this was a good enough reason to accelerate their plans to move off of Jenkins so it got nuked from orbit.  Still not sure what the initial attack vector was; can’t decide whether it’s a hitherto unknown bug in Jenkins or an existing exploit.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the @rutgoff answer. It's a malware.
We found it today in a jenkins instance, It runned a minero miner from yesterday (in our case).
Fortunately we use jenkins inside a docker container so we removed the container and started a new one.